# ADFSv2.1 with aspnet mvc 5 redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, adfs2.0

I'm setting up a development environment to test out the ADFS login mechanism.

I have access to the admin of the ADFS server, and to my knoledge, everything is correctly configured (of course, my knoledge in the subject is very limited).

When I create a new mvc5 web site, I point the metadata URL and the identifier and everything gets generated correclty, but when I launch the site, after entering valid credentials, the browser enters in a 302 redirect loop.

I already did extensive searches on the interweb for solutions and guidance, but the server setup seems ok and I don't touch anything that the mvc project wizard generates for me.

My MVC5 Site is created with this options: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauthonprem

And for the server configuration, I'm following this guide: http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2010/08/13/Installing-ADFS-2-and-Federating-an-Application.aspx up until the part when they create the web site, of course.

Any help will be appreciated

NOTE: Using ADFS v2.1 on Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Is this the "MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '1' seconds" error?

If so, does the endpoint of the RP that you configured in ADFS have a trailing /     ?

e.g.

```
https://xxx/yyy/
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, sorry if that's the case, but I don't configure any endpoint URL on the ADFS, appart of the RP Identifier, which is just a URI to identify the app and does not needs to exists as URL (http endpoint).

Comment: First thing you need to do is to set the Relying Party in ADFS as a WS-Federation RP, and also the return url where you are expecting the token in the MVC application. That's typically the default url https://mymvcapp/. Secondly, disable the custom errors in the MVC application to see if you are having any error when ADFS submits the token to your MVC application. Multiple things could be failing after the token is submitted

Comment: Pablo, thanks, but when i set up the RP Endpoint as WS-Federation, Return Url is disabled,is only active for SAML Logout. Also, custom errors doesn't do anything, i assume that's because the redirect loop is detected by the browser.

Comment: Anyway, tried to configure the WS Federation Enpoint setting URL parameter to the return address on my mvc site with no change in observed behavior. :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying to do SAMLP authentication with ADFS. In my case, the redirect loop was caused the Extended Protection feature in ADFS and Fiddler running in the background.

The solution is to configure Fiddler to authenticate on the client's behalf as described by Eric Lawrence [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/04/fiddler-http-401-authentication-workaround-to-support-channel-binding-tokens-removing-endless-prompts.aspx).

You can also turn off Extended Protection in ADFS:

```
Set-ADFSProperties -ExtendedProtectionTokenCheck None
```